# Angular2 RC2 - Quickstart project cannot generate 2 .umd.js files

Tags: javascript, angular

When working through the quickstart tutorial today at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/ when I got to the step

```
npm start
```

I saw two 404 missing errors:

```
404 GET /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
404 GET /node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js
```

I have copied the systemjs.config.js and other files directly from the tutorial (see below). This is using 2.0.0-rc.2. Do any Angular experts know what is wrong with the quickstart code at the present time? Should I try a webpack tooling instead?

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `packUmd` function should be like:

```
// Bundled (~40 requests):
function packUmd(pkgName) {
  packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { 
     main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', //bundles path
     defaultExtension: 'js' 
  };
}
```

Notice `/bundles/`

Comment: Thanks @yurzui . I confirmed this works, and also confirmed the same by doing a git clone of https://github.com/angular/quickstart and diffing the systemjs.config.js files (not sure why I didn't think of trying that before posting question :). I guess the tutorial examples just is slightly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

How programatically solve this is:

> `function packUmd(pkgName) {
>           if (pkgName != 'router'){
>             packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
>           }
>           else{
>             packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { 
>               main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js',
>               defaultExtension: 'js' 
>             };
>
>           }
>         };`
>   
>   
>   NOTE: **(beginner-alert)** May be not best approach to resolve.